# How to subset a linnet object

Tags: spatstat

I would like to subset a linnet object to get a list of linnet objects. In the helpfile I see that this is possible with a owin object. But I get errors as the syntax is not clear to me and also not clear is the use of `snip` argument in the call to subset.

I want to split linnet based on a user-attribute coming from marks or split a linnet object based on a windows (each window being a polygon from an shapefile)

Could someone please suggest how to subset a linnet based on a factor/window to get a list of linnet objects:

1. Using a user attribute/factor/mark on line segments. 
   Same values of marks are on contagious line segments, so this is ideally similar to using a window.
2. Using polygons as owin.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `L` is a network and `P` is a polygonal window then `L[P]` computes the intersection of `L` and `P`.

The help file for `[.linnet` includes examples which demonstrate the syntax of this command and which show the effect of the argument `snip`.